# Qt: Re setItemWidget is not useful after use takeTopLevelItem

Tags: qt

After I use `takeTopLevelItem`, `setItemWidget` is not successful. The `QCheckBox` is not  shown.

But If I renew the point of m_pDrawBox, it is fine.

Is there anything I am missing?

I want to implement something like change control attribute. The `QTreeWidget(m_pTreeProperty)` will be changed by a different control. So I need take old attribute reset the new attribute into the `QTreeWidget`.

This is my code:

```
qtForm::qtForm(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags): QMainWindow(parent, flags)
    {
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ui.m_pTreeProperty->setColumnCount(2);
    QStringList lstStr;
    lstStr.clear();
    lstStr.append("Property");
    lstStr.append("Value");
    ui.m_pTreeProperty->setHeaderLabels(lstStr);

    QTreeWidgetItem* m_pDrawBoxItem     = new QTreeWidgetItem;
    QCheckBox* m_pDrawBox               = new QCheckBox;
    m_pDrawBoxItem->setText(0,"drawbox");

    ui.m_pTreeProperty->addTopLevelItem(m_pDrawBoxItem);
    ui.m_pTreeProperty->setItemWidget( m_pDrawBoxItem,1,m_pDrawBox);
    ui.m_pTreeProperty->takeTopLevelItem( 0 );
    ui.m_pTreeProperty->addTopLevelItem(m_pDrawBoxItem);
    --m_pDrawBox                = new QCheckBox;
    --m_pDrawBoxItem->setText(0,"drawbox");
    ui.m_pTreeProperty->setItemWidget( m_pDrawBoxItem,1,m_pDrawBox);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`takeTopLevelItem` **removes** the `QTreeWidgetItem` from `QTreeWidget` so you have to save it and readd it.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui.m_pTreeProperty->takeTopLevelItem( 0 );
ui.m_pTreeProperty->addTopLevelItem(item);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think it is not right. When I call addTopLevelItem first, I send a member point to it. takeTopLevelItem will return the same address with the member point. whatever use yours or mine, it is the same address and will not successful,either.